# Grabbing values not between quotation marks (regular expression)

Tags: regex

I want to fetch the word outside a quotation for example if I have this text:

```
  xxxx xxx OK xxxxx "xxx OK xxxx"
```

I want to fetch the "OK" outside the quotation which mean first one
I make this regular expression

```
  [ ]OK[ ]
```

but it fetch the both. So how can I fetch only outside a quotation with regular expression?

Comment: which lang you're running?

Comment: I am use this website http://regexr.com/ to check it.

Comment: what's wrong with https://regex101.com/r/qJ7eI8/1?

Comment: I will use java, but now I check me regular expiration on this website.

Comment: for java use https://regex101.com/r/qJ7eI8/2 and fetch the chars you want from group index 1.

Comment: but this match the both also

Comment: I want only the first OK

Comment: Thanks,  Avinash I got it

Comment: got an answer then delete this question :-)

Comment: but stackoverflow ask me to don't delete the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the combination of caturing group and the regex alternation operator.

```
"[^"]*"|( OK )
```

And now the group index 1 contain the `<space>OR<space>` which exists outside the double quoted part.

Code:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"|( OK )").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```